# To Fix EHCacheProvider Memory Leak Issue in DD4T Java

Tags: dd4t-2, cache, dd4t-java

We are using **DD4T-Java 2.0.5** version in Spring MVC web-application. I was referring to [this](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/dxa-disable-dd4t-ehcache) post which confirmed there is a bug (Memory Leak) in DD4T's `EHCacheProvider` and is fixed in version 2.0.9

1. Will it be correct to say that just replacing the `dd4t-caching.jar` with `dd4t-caching.jar` ver 2.0.9 is required here, or there are other dependent changes also?
2. Will it be safe to use mixture of DD4T version jars, will it result in some new issues?
3. `EHCacheProvider` used in 2.0.5 pasted below for reference:

```
package org.dd4t.core.providers;

import net.sf.ehcache.Cache;
import net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager;
import net.sf.ehcache.Element;
import org.dd4t.core.caching.Cachable;
import org.dd4t.core.caching.CacheElement;
import org.dd4t.core.caching.CacheInvalidator;
import org.dd4t.core.caching.impl.CacheElementImpl;
import org.dd4t.core.services.PropertiesService;
import org.dd4t.core.util.Constants;
import org.dd4t.core.util.TridionUtils;
import org.dd4t.providers.CacheProvider;
import org.dd4t.providers.PayloadCacheProvider;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListSet;

/**
 * EH Cache implementation
 *
 * @author R. Kempees, Mihai Cadariu, Rogier Oudshoorn
 */
public class EHCacheProvider implements PayloadCacheProvider, CacheInvalidator, CacheProvider {

    /**
     * The name of the EHCache that contains the cached items for this
     * application
     */
    public static final String CACHE_NAME = "DD4T-Objects";
    public static final String CACHE_NAME_DEPENDENCY = "DD4T-Dependencies";
    public static final String DEPENDENT_KEY_FORMAT = "%s:%s";

    private final Cache cache = CacheManager.getInstance().getCache(CACHE_NAME);
    private final Cache dependencyCache = CacheManager.create().getCache(CACHE_NAME_DEPENDENCY);

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EHCacheProvider.class);

    public static final int ADJUST_TTL = 2;

    private int expiredTTL = 299;
    private int cacheDependencyTTL = 299;
    private int cacheTTL = 3599;
    private boolean checkForPreview = false;

    @Resource
    private PropertiesService propertiesService;

    public EHCacheProvider () {
        LOG.debug("Starting cache provider");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        expiredTTL = Integer.parseInt(propertiesService.getProperty(Constants.CACHE_EXPIRED_TTL,"299"));
        cacheDependencyTTL = Integer.parseInt(propertiesService.getProperty(Constants.CACHE_DEPENDENCY_TTL,"299"));
        cacheTTL = Integer.parseInt(propertiesService.getProperty(Constants.CACHE_TTL,"3599"));
    }

    public boolean doCheckForPreview () {
        return checkForPreview;
    }

    public void setCheckForPreview (boolean breakOnPreview) {
        this.checkForPreview = breakOnPreview;
    }

    /*
     * Getters and setters for cache TTL's
     */
    public int getCacheDependencyTTL () {
        return cacheDependencyTTL;
    }

    public void setCacheDependencyTTL (int cacheDependencyTTL) {
        this.cacheDependencyTTL = cacheDependencyTTL;
    }

    public int getCacheTTL () {
        return cacheTTL;
    }

    public void setCacheTTL (int cacheTTL) {
        this.cacheTTL = cacheTTL;
    }

    public Cache getDependencyCache () {
        return dependencyCache;
    }

    public int getExpiredTTL () {
        return expiredTTL;
    }

    public void setExpiredTTL (int expiredTTL) {
        this.expiredTTL = expiredTTL;
    }

    /**
     * Loads given object from the cache and returns it inside a CacheItem
     * wrapper.
     *
     * @param key String representing the cache key to retrieve a payload for
     * @return CacheElement object wrapping the actual payload. Return object
     * never null, but it can wrap a null payload. It can also return an
     * expired (stale) payload, which must be updated.
     */
    @Override
    public <T> CacheElement<T> loadPayloadFromLocalCache (String key) {
        if (!doCheckForPreview() || (TridionUtils.getSessionPreviewToken() == null && cache != null)) {
            Element currentElement = cache.get(key);
            if (currentElement == null) {
                currentElement = new Element(key, new CacheElementImpl<T>(null));
                setExpired(currentElement, 0);
                Element oldElement = cache.putIfAbsent(currentElement);
                if (oldElement != null) {
                    currentElement = oldElement;
                }
            }
            CacheElement<T> cacheElement = (CacheElement<T>) currentElement.getObjectValue();
            String dependencyKey = cacheElement.getDependentKey();
            if (dependencyKey != null) {
                Element dependencyElement = dependencyCache.get(dependencyKey); // update
                // LRU
                // stats
                if (dependencyElement == null) { // recover evicted dependent
                    // key
                    addDependency(key, dependencyKey);
                }
            }
            return cacheElement;
        } else {
            LOG.debug("Disable cache for Preview Session Token: {}", TridionUtils.getSessionPreviewToken());
            return new CacheElementImpl<>((T) null, true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Store given item in the cache with a simple time-to-live property.
     *
     * @param key          String representing the key to store the payload under
     * @param cacheElement CacheElement a wrapper around the actual value to store in
     *                     cache
     */
    @Override
    public <T> void storeInItemCache (String key, CacheElement<T> cacheElement) {
        if (cache == null) {
            LOG.error("Cache configuration is invalid! NOT Caching. Check EH Cache configuration.");
            return;
        }
        cacheElement.setExpired(false);
        Element element = new Element(key, cacheElement);
        element.setTimeToLive(cacheTTL);
        if (cache.isKeyInCache(key)) {
            cache.replace(element);
        } else {
            cache.put(element);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Store given item in the cache with a reference to supplied Tridion Item.
     *
     * @param key                    String representing the key to store the cacheItem under
     * @param cacheElement           Object the actual value to store in cache
     * @param dependingPublicationId int representing the Publication id of the Tridion item the
     *                               cacheItem depends on
     * @param dependingItemId        int representing the Item id of the Tridion item the cacheItem
     *                               depends on
     */
    @Override
    public <T> void storeInItemCache (String key, CacheElement<T> cacheElement, int dependingPublicationId, int dependingItemId) {
        if (cache == null) {
            LOG.error("Cache configuration is invalid! NOT Caching. Check EH Cache configuration.");
            return;
        }
        cacheElement.setExpired(false);
        Element element = cache.get(key);
        if (element == null) {
            element = new Element(key, cacheElement);
            cache.put(element);
        }
        element.setTimeToLive(cacheDependencyTTL);
        String dependentKey = getKey(dependingPublicationId, dependingItemId);
        cacheElement.setDependentKey(dependentKey);
        addDependency(key, dependentKey);
        updateTTL(dependencyCache.get(dependentKey));
    }

    @Override
    public void flush () {
        if (cache == null) {
            LOG.error("Cache configuration is invalid! NOT Caching. Check EH Cache configuration.");
            return;
        }
        LOG.info("Expire all items in cache");
        for (Object key : cache.getKeys()) {
            setExpired(cache.get(key), 0);
        }
        for (Object key : dependencyCache.getKeys()) {
            setExpired(dependencyCache.get(key), ADJUST_TTL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void invalidate (final String key) {
        if (dependencyCache == null) {
            LOG.error("Cache configuration is invalid! NOT Caching. Check EH Cache configuration.");
            return;
        }
        String dependencyKey = getKey(key);
        Element dependencyElement = dependencyCache.get(dependencyKey);
        if (dependencyElement != null) {
            LOG.info("Expire key: {} from dependency cache", dependencyKey);
            setExpired(dependencyElement, ADJUST_TTL);
            ConcurrentSkipListSet<String> cacheSet = ((CacheElement<ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>>) dependencyElement.getObjectValue()).getPayload();
            if (cacheSet != null) {
                for (Iterator<String> iterator = cacheSet.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
                    String cacheKey = iterator.next();
                    LOG.debug("Expire cache key: {} from cache", cacheKey);
                    Element cacheElement = cache.get(cacheKey);
                    setExpired(cacheElement, 0);
                }
            }
        } else {
            LOG.info("Attempting to expire key {} but not found in dependency cache", dependencyKey);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Makes the _fromKey_ dependent on _toKey_ It adds the _fromKey_ to the
     * list of values that depend on the _toKey_
     */
    private void addDependency (String cacheKey, String dependencyKey) {
        if (dependencyCache == null) {
            LOG.error("Cache configuration is invalid! NOT Caching. Check EH Cache configuration.");
            return;
        }
        ConcurrentSkipListSet<String> cacheSet = null;
        Element dependencyElement = dependencyCache.get(dependencyKey);
        if (dependencyElement != null) {
            cacheSet = ((CacheElement<ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>>) dependencyElement.getObjectValue()).getPayload();
            setNotExpired(dependencyElement);
        }
        if (cacheSet == null) {
            LOG.debug("Add empty dependencies for key: {} to cache", dependencyKey);
            cacheSet = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();
            CacheElementImpl<ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>> cacheElement = new CacheElementImpl<ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>>(cacheSet);
            Element newElement = new Element(dependencyKey, cacheElement);
            newElement.setTimeToLive(cacheDependencyTTL);
            Element oldElement = dependencyCache.putIfAbsent(newElement);
            if (oldElement != null) {
                ConcurrentSkipListSet<String> oldCacheSet = ((CacheElement<ConcurrentSkipListSet<String>>) oldElement.getObjectValue()).getPayload();
                if (oldCacheSet != null) {
                    cacheSet.addAll(oldCacheSet);
                }
            }
        }
        LOG.debug("Add dependency from key: {} to key: {}", dependencyKey, cacheKey);
        cacheSet.add(cacheKey);
    }

    public void setExpired (Element element, int adjustTTL) {
        if (element == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (element.getObjectValue() instanceof CacheElement) {
            CacheElement cacheElement = (CacheElement) element.getObjectValue();
            if (!cacheElement.isExpired()) {
                cacheElement.setExpired(true);
                expireElement(element, adjustTTL);
            }
        } else {
            expireElement(element, adjustTTL);
        }
    }

    private void expireElement (Element element, int adjustTTL) {
        long lastAccessTime = element.getLastAccessTime();
        long creationTime = element.getCreationTime();
        // set element eviction to ('now' + expiredTTL) seconds in the future
        int timeToLive = lastAccessTime == 0 ? expiredTTL : (int) (lastAccessTime - creationTime) / 1000 + expiredTTL;
        timeToLive += adjustTTL;
        element.setTimeToLive(timeToLive);
    }

    /*
     * Sets an element from DependencyCache to not expired. Updates its TTL.
     */
    private void setNotExpired (Element dependentElement) {
        if (dependentElement == null) {
            return;
        }
        CacheElement cacheElement = (CacheElement) dependentElement.getObjectValue();
        if (cacheElement.isExpired()) {
            cacheElement.setExpired(false);
            updateTTL(dependentElement);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Update TTL of element from DependencyCache to 'now' + cacheDependencyTTL
     * + adjustTTL
     */
    private void updateTTL (Element dependentElement) {
        if (dependentElement == null) {
            return;
        }
        long lastAccessTime = dependentElement.getLastAccessTime();
        long creationTime = dependentElement.getCreationTime();
        int timeToLive = lastAccessTime == 0 ? cacheDependencyTTL : (int) (lastAccessTime - creationTime) / 1000 + cacheDependencyTTL;
        timeToLive += ADJUST_TTL;
        dependentElement.setTimeToLive(timeToLive);
    }

    private static String getKey (Serializable key) {
        String[] parts = ((String) key).split(":");
        switch (parts.length) {
            case 0:
                return "";
            case 1:
                return String.format(DEPENDENT_KEY_FORMAT, parts[0], "");
            default:
                return String.format(DEPENDENT_KEY_FORMAT, parts[0], parts[1]);
        }
    }

    private static String getKey (int publicationId, int itemId) {
        return String.format(DEPENDENT_KEY_FORMAT, publicationId, itemId);
    }

    @Override
    public Object loadFromLocalCache (String key) {
        CacheElement<Object> item = loadPayloadFromLocalCache(key);

        if (item.isExpired()) {
            LOG.debug("Not returning expired item");
            return null;
        } else {
            return item.getPayload();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void storeInCache (String key, Cachable ob, Collection<Cachable> deps) {
        if (cache == null) {
            LOG.error("Cache configuration is invalid! NOT Caching. Check EH Cache configuration.");
            return;
        }
        CacheElement<Object> cacheElement = loadPayloadFromLocalCache(key);
        cacheElement.setPayload(ob);

        storeInItemCache(key, cacheElement);

        for (Cachable item : deps) {
            addDependency(key, item.getCacheKey());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void storeInItemCache (String key, Object ob, int dependingPublicationId, int dependingItemId) {
        CacheElement<Object> cacheElement = loadPayloadFromLocalCache(key);
        cacheElement.setPayload(ob);

        storeInItemCache(key, cacheElement, dependingPublicationId, dependingItemId);
    }

    @Override
    public void storeInComponentPresentationCache (String key, Object ob, int dependingPublicationId, int dependingCompId, int dependingTemplateId) {
        CacheElement<Object> cacheElement = loadPayloadFromLocalCache(key);
        cacheElement.setPayload(ob);

        storeInItemCache(key, cacheElement, dependingPublicationId, dependingCompId);
    }

    @Override
    public void storeInKeywordCache (String key, Object ob, int dependingPublicationId, int dependingItemId) {
        CacheElement<Object> cacheElement = loadPayloadFromLocalCache(key);
        cacheElement.setPayload(ob);

        storeInItemCache(key, cacheElement, dependingPublicationId, dependingItemId);
    }

    public void setPropertiesService (final PropertiesService propertiesService) {
        this.propertiesService = propertiesService;
    }
}
```