# what is the Stable Version for DD4T Java with JMS DD4T Cache Implementation

Tags: dd4t-2, cache, dd4t-java

At present we are using DD4T 2.0.5 (java) but because of dd4t bug confirmed in this [POST](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/dxa-disable-dd4t-ehcache) for caching we need to switch dd4t to a higher version. What is the stable version of DD4T (java) which works perfectly for DD4T cache implementation where JMS used for cache invalidation. Please share comments on same.

Also the DD4T Template version used in cms is 2.0.8. we dont want this to be upgrade right now (time constraint) to fix above issue. Thanks

Comment: It wasn't a bug in DD4T necessarily, it was a wrong cache calculation. 2.0.5 will generally work fine. That issue is fixed in 2.0.9 as is stated in the other post.

Comment: @ Raimond, Thanks for the comment. 1)Can you please confirm api 2.0.9 compatible with template 2.0.8 version . 2)Is there a compatibility list defined some where for template version and api version. 3) For every new api version launched is it some where listed what changes,  issues fixed in that version release; that info will be helfpul. thanks

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) No, not really. 3) Best to check the commits. Bear in mind it's open source and we all work on this in our spare time. :)